# Passenger could not spawn process for application. Rails, ubuntu, passenger and apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

My application is crashing again and again. [I am using the hosting services of digital ocean the status of the server are also displayed in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9Qx6.png)
(It start working when I restart the server but that is not the solution. After sometime it again crashes.)
Apache log.error shows:

```
[ 2016-07-05 16:40:39.2615 1768/7ff87c09b700 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/abc/kbs: An er$
  Error ID: b1aaad3d
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-ygdDZS.html
  Message from application: An error occurred while starting the web application. It exited before signalling successful startup back to Phusion$
<h2>Raw process output:</h2>
(empty)

App 21534 stdout:   ^[[1m^[[35mCategoryProduct Load (23.0ms)^[[0m  SELECT "category_products".* FROM "category_products" WHERE "category_product$
App 21534 stdout:   ^[[1m^[[36m (0.5ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT "category_products"."name" FROM "category_products" WHERE "category_products"."product$
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Passenger::SystemException'
App 21534 stdout:   ^[[1m^[[35mCACHE (0.3ms)^[[0m  SELECT  "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."id" = $1  ORDER BY name LIMIT 1  [[$
  what():  Cannot fork a new process: Cannot allocate memory (errno=12)
ERROR: cannot fork a process for executing 'tee'
[ pid=1768, timestamp=1467751239 ] Process aborted! signo=SIGABRT(6), reason=SI_TKILL, signal sent by PID 1768 with UID 0, si_addr=0x6e8, random$
[ pid=1768 ] Could not create crash log file, so dumping to stderr only.
[ pid=1768 ] Could fork a child process for dumping diagnostics: fork() failed with errno=12
```

Content of the file /tmp/passenger-error-ygdDZS.html are below.

```
An error occurred while starting the web application. It exited before signalling successful startup back to Phusion Passenger. Please read this article for more information about this problem.
Raw process output:

(empty)
Error ID
b1aaad3d
Application root
/home/abc_user/app_name
Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV, NODE_ENV and PASSENGER_APP_ENV)
production
Ruby interpreter command
/usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby
User and groups
uid=1000(abc_user) gid=1000(abc_user) groups=1000(abc_user),27(sudo)
Environment variables
APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
SHELL=/bin/bash
APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
PASSENGER_DEBUG_DIR=/tmp/passenger.spawn-debug.XXXXijaXyT
USER=abc_user
PASSENGER_USE_FEEDBACK_FD=true
APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2
PATH=/home/abc_user/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/abc_user/.rbenv/shims:/home/abc_user/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/home/abc_user/app_name
APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
LANG=C
NODE_PATH=/usr/share/passenger/node
RBENV_SHELL=bash
SHLVL=0
HOME=/home/abc_user
LOGNAME=abc_user
SERVER_SOFTWARE=Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/5.0.26
APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2
APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/run/apache2
IN_PASSENGER=1
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RAILS_ENV=production
RACK_ENV=production
WSGI_ENV=production
NODE_ENV=production
PASSENGER_APP_ENV=production
SCRIPT_URL=/products/spray-paints-hand-tools
SCRIPT_URI=https://www.domain.com/products/name_of_brand
HTTPS=on
SSL_TLS_SNI=www.domain.com
Ulimits
Unknown
System metrics
------------- General -------------
Kernel version    : 3.13.0-79-generic
Uptime            : 8h 41m 28s
Load averages     : 4.03%, 2.24%, 0.96%
Fork rate         : unknown

------------- CPU -------------
Number of CPUs    :    2
Average CPU usage : 100%  -- 100% user,   0% nice,   0% system,   0% idle
  CPU 1           : 100%  -- 100% user,   0% nice,   0% system,   0% idle
  CPU 2           : 100%  -- 100% user,   0% nice,   0% system,   0% idle
I/O pressure      :   0%
  CPU 1           :   0%
  CPU 2           :   0%
Interference from other VMs:   0%
  CPU 1                    :   0%
  CPU 2                    :   0%

------------- Memory -------------
RAM total         :   2001 MB
RAM used          :   1879 MB (94%)
RAM free          :    122 MB
Swap total        :      0 MB
Swap used         :      0 MB (-nan%)
Swap free         :      0 MB
Swap in           : unknown
Swap out          : unknown
```

Some information about my server is

Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

Server built: Jan 14 2016 17:45:23

Phusion Passenger 5.0.26

Memory(Ram) 2GB
Disc Space 40Gb

Comment: The error message is very clear: The virtual machine ran out of memory.

Comment: You are right but why it is running out of memory. My application is too simple and not so heavy.

Answer (score 1):

Please post the following from your httpd.conf or other configuration file for the given apache server:::

```
StartServers          ?
MinSpareServers       ?
MaxSpareServers      ?
```

Could be you are starting way more spare servers than the server can handle for your load of simple web application. Passenger runs inside apache and forks from it.

Comment: StartServers          2
MaxClients           10
MinSpareThreads      25
MaxSpareThreads      75
ThreadsPerChild      25
MaxRequestsPerChild   100